# How to formulate SQL prepare statement with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, prepared-statement, insert-update

I am using prepare statement in WP, and i need the same one with addition "WHERE". I must be prepare.  I have tried to put it after values, but doesnt work. It works when I am using without "WHERE", but this time I really need this kind of statement.

Bellow you can find what I have tried. Moreover, I have tried to put "$zan_id" after other values, but doesn't work

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO wp_tool
                ( tool_id,  tool_content , tool_title)
                VALUES ( %d, %s , %s) WHERE id=$zan_id
                ",
                $tool,
                $tool_content,
                $tool_title
            ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use INSERT for new table entries.  If the entries already exist you should use UPDATE
eg.

```
 UPDATE wp_tool SET tool_id=$tool, tool_content=$tool_content, tool_title=$tool_title WHERE id=$zan_id
```

Also, since you're using pdo, you should do the following

```
$wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_tool SET tool_id=?, tool_content=?, tool_title=? WHERE id=?");
$wpdb->execute(array($tool,$tool_content,$tool_title,$zan_id));
```

That is also assuming you have pdo configured correctly, that is, to ignore types when binding the parameters.

Comment: . . I modestly reformatted the code so I could upvote the answer.

Comment: I know that, and I have tried, but I dont want to update entire table, I need just those three fields. BUT, i need to add new values in those fiels, not to overried those that already exist. For example, i have saved id = 185, and new value is 255, i need to have in fields 185 255. bouth of them. Can I do it somehow with update?

Comment: @user3042036 Yes, I showed you how to use the update command in the answer.  If you scroll over to the right, you will see that the filter is being used.